# Get first value from in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, view, datatable, multiple-columns

I have column in mysql table

```
uid ,  valueid , date 
11 ,    23,      "2019-01-01"
11 ,    24,      "2019-02-01"
11 ,    22,      "2019-05-01"
```

i want result in this format

```
id , valueid , date
11 , 23 , "2019-01-01"
```

get always first value id i.e is 23

Comment: What's the rule you used? Do you mean... by date?

Comment: Just to confirm, is 23 considered the first value because it has the earliest date?

Comment: Define "first".  Unless you specify an ordering then there's no meaningful concept of "first, second, third, etc."

Answer (score 1):

If by first value you mean the one with the minimum date, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select min(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.uid = t.uid);
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `(uid, date)`.

Comment: skip date column get from valueid initial

Comment: @ShubhamSeth: Can you clarify what you mean by that?  The language barrier appears to be pretty significant here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT`, as in:

```
select * from t order by date limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as
(
   select *, row_number() over (partition by uid order by date) as rn
   from your_table   
)
select * from t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: skip date column

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.